# How can i convert android gradle project to an ant based project

Tags: android, ant, android-gradle-plugin

I want to try out android 5 samples but iam looking for a way to convert the gradle projects to ant which i am more used to . Most of the samples out there are about switching from ant to gradle but i want to remain with the old build system.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way is to **create an empty Eclipse/Ant project** and manually copy all the necessary files in it:

- java sources in **src/**
- all the resources in **res/** (keeping all the subfolders structure)
- libraries in **libs/** (checking all the libs are correctly set in the project's classpath)
- **AndroidManifest.xml** in the project's root

It's like a 30 seconds job ;)

Comment: show me an example using the google IO opensource app https://github.com/google/iosched

Comment: @bonnyz: How can you resolve gradle dependency project ?